# Vue.js - how to sort and objects inside the array by particular property and render it with "v-for"

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array with a few objects inside. Each object contains a few properties.

I use vue.js v-for method to render it in the list.

But I cannot render it in the specific order of the given property. I use this function to sort it ascending:

```
    evenNumbers: function () {
      return this.numbers.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
    }
```

It works fine with a simple array like [22, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. But it does not work for the objects like this:

```
      numbers2: [
      {
        name: 'Alan',
        age: 72
      }, 
      {
        name: 'Thomas',
        age: 32
      }, 
      {
        name: 'Thomas',
        age: 32
      }, 
      {
        name: 'Michal',
        age: 32
      },
    ]
  }
```

I want to sort them by the age in the ascending order.

At the end I want to render them inside the li for example only {{ age }} property.

Here is a snippet with my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/marektchas/jyznx475/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you now have complex objects, sorting by the object directly won't work as you expect (the operator runs some implicit conversions resulting in `NaN` for every comparison).

You must sort by the **specific** property, in this case, `age`.  So:

```
    evenNumbers2: function () {
      return this.numbers2.sort(function (a, b) { return a.age - b.age });
    }
```

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/5knh47yg/).

Comment: But how to render now inside the <li> for example only {{ age }} property?

Comment: All you need to do is use the dot notation in the template as well: `<li v-for="n in evenNumbers2">{{ n.name }}'s age is {{ n.age }}!</li>`  see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/5knh47yg/2/